# Draw this picture in Latex template. (Complex 1)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Draw this picture in Latex template. (Complex 1)
Draw this picture in Latex [image]template. With respect

---

With respect

Comment: Please remember that SE isn't a free service site where you can ask for someone to do your work for you. At least show your best effort at this point. If you don't know where to start, go to the [TikZ CTAN page] and read the provided tutorial. Then you can come back here asking about precise aspects of your code.

Comment: If there is a service, we will do it. Please help me draw beautifully. With respect and best regards Jonibek

Comment: I mistyped the link in my first comment, so here it is again: [TikZ CTAN page](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf). Read the "Minimal introduction to TikZ" first and, if necessary, there is a more complete tutorial in the main manual.

Comment: I didn't understand it very well, help me, draw it. I will be active.

Comment: Best regards and with respect

Comment: If you are interested in paying for LaTeX consulting see https://tug.org/consultants.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! There are plenty of examples on this site. There are many ways to draw such a diagram, the most popular probably being using Ti*k*Z of which there exists a [great manual with tutorials](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (as already pointed out in the comments).

To give you a starting point:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% origin
\coordinate (o) at (0,0) node[below left] {$0$};

% x axis
\draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$t$};

% y axis
\draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[left] {$R$};

% main plot
\draw[->] (0,0) -- node[above] {$p$} (3,3) node[above right] {$s$};

% coordinate lines
\draw[dashed] (0,3) -- node[above] {$e_1$} (3,3) 
                    -- node[right] {$e_2$} (3,0) node[below] {$c$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. We did it this way.

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}

% origin
\coordinate (o) at (0,0) node[below left] {$O$};

% x axis
\draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$x$};

% y axis
\draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[left] {$iy$};

% main plot
\draw[->] (0,0) -- node[above] {$r$} (3,3) node[above right] {$M$};

% coordinate lines
\draw[dashed] (0,3) -- node[above] {$y$} (3,3)
                    -- node[right] {$x$} (3,0) node[below] {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}